# Twitter msgs using jQuery and some logic

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add some logic to `twitter tweets`. You can post `5` tweets and when you post the `6th` tweet the `1st` tweet gets deleted. I believe I have to add some kind of logic in order to accomplish this. I would appreciate if someone can guide me through the logic and I will try applying that logic to see if it works. I'm new to `programming` so, please help me. I created this fiddle :-

https://jsfiddle.net/drq72pgd/12/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just use the pop() function here, because its not just an JavaScript array. You are manipulating the DOM.

Steps in your msgs function:

1. Select all your tweets with jQuery
2. Check if the tweets.size() is larger than 5 (tweets.length should
   work, too)
3. Select the last element of your list items
4. Remove the last item from the DOM with [.remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Try this code:

```
var main = function() {

$('.btn').click(function(){
  var post = $('.status-box').val();

  $('<li>').text(post).prependTo('.posts');
  $('.status-box').val(''); 

  // call you helper function
  msgs();
});

// your helper function
var msgs = function() {
  // get your tweets
  var tweets = $('.posts li');
  // check if you have more than five tweets
  if( tweets.size() > 5) {
    // find last element of your list-items
    var lastTweet = $('.posts li:last-child')
    // remove last item
    lastTweet.remove();
  }
}

}//end of main function

$(document).ready(main);
```

There are shorter and more elegant ways to write this, but I kept it close to your code.

Updated [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/drq72pgd/41/)

Comment: Matt this is awesome...i really appreciate it.